# Parameter Estimation on S1 model

Tags: regression, estimation, maximum-likelihood, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I have the following model of creating a random graph on the circle:
First, N nodes are uniformly distributed on the circle of radius $N/(2\pi)$ to give a node density of $1$. We sample the expected degree of each node, $\kappa$, from a Pareto distribution and denote $\overline{\kappa}$ to be the expectation of this distribution. Using the following connection probability between nodes $i$ and $j$, we should then get the desired expected degrees for large N:
$$
p_{ij} = \frac{1}{1+\Big(\frac{2I\overline{\kappa}d_{ij}}{\kappa_i\kappa_j}\Big)^{\beta}},
$$
where $\beta > 1$, $d_{ij}$ is the arc-length distance, and $I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{\beta}}dx$ .

My question: given a real network with a known adjacency matrix (thus, degrees are known and can be used to estimate the $\kappa_i's$) and known angular coordinates (thus, $d_{ij}$ are known), how can one estimate parameter $\beta$ (for example using python)?

Any help is much appreciated, as I am completely stuck.

Comment: You refer to both $\kappa$ and $p_{ij}$ as "expected degrees:" please explain how that can be.

Comment: p_ij is the connection probability that guarantees the chosen expected degrees for large n. Maybe it's easier to view this problem as a maximum likelihood problem of Bernoulli distributions that are not identically distributed